# Count the size of $|\{(b_1, \dots, b_n): (-1)^{b_1} a_1 + \cdots + (-1)^{b_n} a_n =0, b_i \in \{0,1\} \}|$ in $O(n)$ way

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

What is the size of $|\{(b_1, \dots, b_n): (-1)^{b_1} a_1 + \cdots + (-1)^{b_n} a_n =0, b_i \in \{0,1\} \}|$ when all $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ are given, fixed positive integers ? How can you count this size in a $O(n)$ way (especially by computer algorithm)? **What is a main trick to count this in a fast way?** Is there any textbook or topics that deals with such things?

Comment: @MorganRodgers, yes very trivial way, which takes $2^n/4$ steps to count the size

Answer (score 0):

Let us rewrite the main condition as 
$$
\tag{1} (-1)^{b_1}a_1 +...+(-1)^{b_n} a_n = \sum\limits_{i: b_i = 1} a_i - \sum\limits_{i: b_i = -1} a_i = 0,
$$
and hence the equivalent formulation of your question is to find the number of subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$  which partition $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ into $2$ sets with equal sums. In this you have the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is **NP-complete**. In fact, the **partition problem** asks for *existence* of a single partition satisfying $(1)$, while you want to compute all possible ones, so no polynomial algorithm here, let alone linear $O(n)$ as you ask.

There is, however, an approach via **dynamic programming**, which is easy to program and might suffice for many practical scenarios. I'm sketching the idea below, a **python** program (this is closest to pseudo-code and requires less explanation of the syntax), which, given a list of integers $a$, decides if there's a partition with equal sums.

```
def partition(a):
    # a is the array in question
    # we decide whether there is a partition of a into equal sum subsets

    num = sum(a)
    if num%2 != 0:
        return False

    num = num//2
    n = len(a)

    memo = (num+1)*[None]       # will be used for memoization, see below
    for i in range(num + 1):
        memo[i] = (n+1)*[False]

    # memo[i][j] shows if the integer i can be represented by elements of a up to and including j

    for i in range(n+1):
        memo[0][i] = True # 0 can be represented by not choosing anything, the empty set

    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            memo[i][j] =  memo[i][j-1] or ( i >= a[j-1] and memo[i - a[j-1]][j-1] )  
            # either integer i can be represented by elements a_0, ..., a_{j-1}
            # or i is represented by a_j and i - a_j by elements a_0,...,a_{j-1} 

    return memo[-1][-1] # the last element of the last row
```

The result of the function *partition* will give you whether such equal sum partition exists. Then, you can use **backtracking algorithms** and the values of the matrix memo to construct the actual partitions.

The above is a well-known topic and you will find further details and plenty of resources on the internet.